# Limit Remote Assistance to domain administrators only

Tags: active-directory, remote-access

I'm an IT administrator in my company.
Currently we use Active Directory managed by Windows Server 2012R2 and most workstations use Windows 10.

We are looking into using Microsoft's built-in Remote Assistance tool to support our employees.
Is it possible to limit access to devices only to certain group of people (e.g. IT admins)? The idea is to prevent employees from allowing people outside the company to access their computers.
RDP is not good for this purpose because it requires either login with different credentials (which may put us outside the scope of the fault we're trying to solve) or asking for remote user's credentials which is against our security policy.

Thank you

Comment: Just a point of recommendation (based upon the title), Domain Admins should not have administrative access to workstations; ideally not even used to login to them.  Follow joeqwerty's advice to configure Remote Assistance to allow a delegated group of user accounts dedicated to the purpose of workstation administration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two Group Policy settings that you'll want to configure, both under:

Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>System>Remote Assistance:

Configure Offer Remote Assistance

Configure Solicited Remote Assistance